# Install xgb rserver

Tags: r, compiler-errors, xgboost

I'm trying to install xgboost in R -server free.
I got this error:

```
Error in .shlib_internal(args) : 
  C++14 standard requested but CXX14 is not defined
* removing ‘/home/bogdan.dumitrascu/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/xgboost’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xgboost’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried everything:
https://blogs.cornell.edu/jingyi/2020/02/04/rstudio-install-xtensor/#.YS5zRY4zZPZ
Or delete all the objects and restart the session. Nothing works.

Pls, I need help! It is very important!
Thank you!

Comment: Your R is likely too old just like your RedHat version is likely too old.

Comment: Or your compiler (which is often driven by the OS version). Check `system("g++ --version")`, if it returns something older than 5.0.0 (I believe), you are unlikely to be able to compile `xgboost` on that machine.

Comment: It returns `g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44.0.3)`. What should to do?

Comment: The link you provided links to https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-shlib-internal-args-c-14-standard-requested-but-cxx14-is-not-defined/16819 which links to https://community.rstudio.com/t/installing-rstan-on-centos7-the-version-of-gcc-is-4-8-5-does-not-seem-to-support-cxx14/17092, which states *"you cannot, you need more recent gcc"*. I'm not an authority on it; @DirkEddelbuettel is much more experienced here, and his comment is consistent with that last post.

Comment: (I was busy above.  "Too old RHEL" is very much the case -- but also means "compiler too old".  And "they know" and you can get local help via something call (if I recall correctly)  'devtoolset' -- have your sysadmins install that. It will help, and still a little bit of help to use.  Try to get a newer R too.  You can google for 'newer gcc on RHHEL 4.8' to find out more.)